# Fastest way to check for bad sectors in HDD?

Tags: hard-drive, badblocks

I have a bunch of disks, probably 50 or more laying there, I know some of them are broken and some should still work fine, I need a way to check them without wasting days.

Do you know any tools besides badblocks, that can do it without taking too much time?

Comment: Take a look at [fsck](http://linux.die.net/man/8/fsck).

Comment: isn't that for linux file systems?

Comment: It is.  What file system(s) are you using?

Comment: The hard drives may have different file systems, i need to check the hardware for bad sectors regardless of their OS.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to check some [SMART](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.) utilities.

You can use "Disk Utility" (aka palimpsest or gnome-disks depending on the Ubuntu release) for this.

In command line I suggest you install the smartmontools package (`sudo apt install smartmontools`) and play around with `smartctl`.

Example:

```
sudo smartctl --all /dev/sda
```

Comment: http://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/SMART_tests_with_smartctl#Short_Test I found more info here.

Answer (score 3):

For those who find this question looking for a solution to the `badblocks` error `Value too large for defined data type` (as you might get trying to scan a 6TB drive): try setting larger block size:

```
badblocks -b 4096 /dev/sde
```

Answer (score 3):

If your drives have SMART, I would go about this by installing "gsmartcontrol" and doing a short test on all drives. Then throw away the ones that do not even pass the short test or display errors/warnings and perform a long test on the remaining drives.

To truly find out if a drive is damaged or not, I guess you will need to check every sector of it and that's what the long test does.

But I am no expert, maybe there is a better way?